# what is the advantage to configure the network ETH with UUID?

Tags: linux, networking, uuid, bonding, lan

what is the advantage to configure the network with UUID?

```
uuidgen eno093736
1b64d026-c6a6-447c-85aa-40c5d2db2c4e
```

for example we want to configure BOND under /etc/sysconfig/network-script

what is the positive thing that we configure the BOND with UUID?

```
UUID=ef23ca7b-93d6-4b40-9fa0-4a9b208914e50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that`s because if you scan your NIC ports again or update your OS, the device names may change. its like filesystems. in fstab you should always enter uuid of LUN because sometimes after a reboot the lun names will change. but uuids of ports or LUNs never change.